# How long to cook dry brined turkey?

Tags: turkey

I have a thawed, dry brined 22 lb turkey.  Does anyone know how long it'll take to cook it and what temp? Thank you!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. How will you be cooking it?

Answer (score 1):

According to a highly rated recipe from [Food Network](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/food-network-kitchens/dry-brined-turkey-with-classic-herb-butter-recipe.html) for dry brined turkey:

> Put the oven rack in the lowest position; preheat the oven to 350 degrees F. Put the turkey breast-side up on a rack in a large roasting pan, tucking the wing tips under. Tie the drumsticks together with twine. Roast until the skin is golden brown and a thermometer inserted into the thigh registers 165 degrees F, about 15 minutes per pound. Transfer to a cutting board and let rest 30 minutes before carving.

Keep in mind that there are a lot of variables. Your thermometer is your friend. If the turkey is stuffed, it could take as long as 7.5 hours.

Comment: For a turkey that large, you might have better results if you drop the temperature to 325.  If the cooking time is 5.5 hours at 350, maybe you don't want to drop it after all, but I'm channeling a Cooks Illustrated recipe that used a wet-brined 22 pound bird.  They crisped the skin at 425 degrees for an hour (breasts down in a foil-lined V-rack), then flipped the bird over and roasted at 325 for 4 hours or so.  I think I'm going to start cooking a turkey in October every year to test some of this stuff out. :)